# Lower bound on quadratic function of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{V}([X,X^2])$

Tags: probability

**Setting:**

Let $X$ be a random variable. Define $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$ and
$$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{V}(X) & Cov(X,X^2) \\ Cov(X,X^2) & \mathbb{V}(X^2) \end{bmatrix} $$
Suppose that $\mathbb{V}(X) \ge \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. Now consider the following function:
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix} 2\mu & 1 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma \begin{bmatrix} 2\mu \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

**Question:**

Does there exist a constant $\alpha > 0$, such that $H \ge \alpha$?

Imposing stronger conditions to get a result or a counter-example would also be welcome.